# C++ Ftp file upload compile error (Codelite)

Tags: c++, ftp

I wrote this code for uploading file through ftp. But, i can't compile with Codelite. I'm using latest codelite witn mingw. Please help me.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <wininet.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    HINTERNET hSession = InternetOpen(NULL, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, NULL, NULL, 0);
    HINTERNET hService = InternetConnect(hSession, "www.server.com", INTERNET_DEFAULT_FTP_PORT, "username", "password", INTERNET_SERVICE_FTP, INTERNET_FLAG_PASSIVE, 0);
    FtpPutFile(hService, "filename.ext", "filename.ext", FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_BINARY, 0);
    InternetCloseHandle(hService);
    InternetCloseHandle(hSession);

    return 0;
}
```

This is error code.

```
./Release/main.cpp.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x40): undefined reference to `InternetOpenA@20'
./Release/main.cpp.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x85): undefined reference to `InternetConnectA@32'
./Release/main.cpp.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x62): undefined reference to `FtpPutFileA@20'
./Release/main.cpp.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x6d): undefined reference to `InternetCloseHandle@4'
./Release/main.cpp.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x78): undefined reference to `InternetCloseHandle@4'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code compiles just fine, you are having a link errors

[According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385096(v=vs.85).aspx), you need to link against `Wininet`

To do this in [codelite IDE](http://codelite.org) open the project settings (click on the wrench icon under the **Workspace** tab) navigate to **Common Settings -> Linker**

And simply paste the name of the library under the **Libraries** field ( see attached screenshot )

HTH,

Eran

[image]